# Integral of the product of a monotonic function with a continuous function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have a problem trying to make a proof of the following proposition:

Let $\varphi$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and $h$ a monotonic function on $[a,b]$.
Then, there exist $c\in(a,b)$ such that

$\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}h(x)\varphi(x)dx=h(b^{-})\int_{c}^{b}\varphi(x)dx+h(a^{+})\int_{a}^{c}\varphi(x)dx$

I considered the following function:

$\displaystyle f(t)=h(b^{-})\int_{t}^{b}\varphi(x)dx+h(a^{+})\int_{a}^{t}\varphi(x)dx-\int_{a}^{b}h(x)\varphi(x)dx$

I tried to show that $f(a)>0$ and $f(b)<0$ or $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)>0$ because $f$ is continuous, but I dont have information about $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}h(x)\varphi(x)dx$ .

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $h(b^{-})$ is the left limit and $h(a^{+})$ the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all note that $h$ is defined in $a$ and $b$, so $h\left(a^{+}\right)=h\left(a\right),\, h\left(b^{-}\right)=h\left(b\right).$ You can find a proof here http://planetmath.org/secondintegralmeanvaluetheorem .